# WSGI : Cookies can only be called after the ** start_response **?

Tags: mod-wsgi, wsgi

I can not call a cookie right after the:

```
 def application(environ, start_response):
```

like this:

```
import Cookie
co = Cookie.SimpleCookie()

def application(environ, start_response):
co.load(environ['HTTP_COOKIE'])

start_response('200 OK', ('Content-Type', 'text/html'))
```

because although this works.. the cookie must already be set for it to work.

if the cookie does not exist.. the script will fail.

the only solution seems to be..

placing this UNDER the "start_response()"

```
if 'HTTP_COOKIE' in environ:
    co.load(environ['HTTP_COOKIE'])

a = co.get('a') and co['a'].value
```

in other words:

```
import Cookie
co = Cookie.SimpleCookie()

def application(environ, start_response):

    start_response('200 OK', ('Content-Type', 'text/html'))

    if 'HTTP_COOKIE' in environ:
        co.load(environ['HTTP_COOKIE'])

    a = co.get('a') and co['a'].value

    yield str(a)
```

but is this method rather not strange given that we are asking for something from

```
 environ
```

and yet it has to be UNDER

```
start_response()
```

in order for it to get the cookie.